# How to get key occurence in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, protractor

I have a json file in this format.

```
[
  {
    "description": "testcase1",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 1246
  },
  {
    "description": "testcase2",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 4
  }
]
```

READ JSON

```
var fs = require('fs');
contents = fs.readFileSync('./update_result.json');
jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);

 it('get', function(){
        var str = jsonContent.getText('assertions');
        console.log(str.count());
    })
```

What I want is to get the count of all the occurences of the word "assertions"

Comment: Is "assertions" always going to be a key name? And does every object in the array have a key called "assertions"?

Comment: yes, i will always need to find the word assertion

Comment: instead of var str = jsonContent.getText('assertions')    use var str = jsonContent.assertions;

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something but if assertions is a key in every object in the array then wouldn't just getting the length of the array get you the number of occurences?

Comment: @ElPedro exactly what's confusing me..

Comment: and how do i get the assertion's value, like if it is passed or fail?

Comment: My actual requirement is getting every occurence of 'assertions' and then get its correspoding value like tru/fail

Comment: you need assertions values to another list!!

Comment: Can the "assertions"-array contain anything beside the object seen? Can this object contain more than the one key-value pair? Do you just need the total amount of "passed" and "failed" assertions?

Answer (score 0):

The label assertions appears in every object in the array so getting the length of the array will give you the number of occurences.

Lets assume that your json is held in a variable called json.

```
json[x]["assertion"]
```

will give you the value where x is the index of the object in the array which in this case would be

```
[("passed":true}]
```

To access the true or false just use

```
json[x]["assertion"][0]["passed"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var fs = require('fs');
contents = fs.readFileSync('./update_result.json');
jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);

var assertionsTrue = [];
var assertionsFail = [];
var totalAssertionCount = 0;

it('get', function(){

    for(var i=0;i<jsonContent.length;i++){

        if(jsonContent[i].assertions != null && jsonContent[i].assertions != undefined){

            totalAssertionCount++;

            if(jsonContent[i].assertions.passed == true)
                assertionsTrue.push(jsonContent[i].assertions);
            else
                assertionsFail.push(jsonContent[i].assertions);
        }
    }
    console.log(totalAssertionCount);
})
```

You will get the occurrence of True Assertions in `assertionsTrue` list and fail Assertions in `assertionsFail` and total occurrence of Assertions in `totalAssertionCount`

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to get only **count of keys in array of object**, you can try string parsing instead

```js
function getKeyCount(searchKey, obj) {
  var r = new RegExp('"' + searchKey + '":', 'g');
  return (JSON.stringify(obj).match(r) || []).length;
}

var d = [{
  "description": "testcase1",
  "assertions": [{
    "passed": true
  }],
  "duration": 1246
}, {
  "description": "testcase2",
  "assertions": [{
    "passed": true
  }],
  "duration": 4
}, {
  "description": "description",
  "duration": 4
}];

console.log(getKeyCount('assertions', d))
console.log(getKeyCount('description', d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
 var j=0;
 for(i = 0; i < jsonContent.length; i++) 
   {
     if(jsonContent[i].assertions)
       {
          j++;
       }
   }
   console.log("assertions:"+j);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something similar to:

```
 var myObj = [
  {
    "description": "testcase1",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 1246
  },
  {
    "description": "testcase2",
    "assertions": [
      {
        "passed": true
      }
    ],
    "duration": 4
  }
]

var counter = 0;
Array.prototype.getOccurence = function(arr){
    return ++counter
}
for (var key in myObj){

    var nodes = myObj[key];
    Array.prototype.getOccurence(myObj[key].assertions) 

}
console.log('Assertion occured :' + counter + "time")
```